# R programming-Survey Function (SVYBY)

Tags: r, stata, mean, subtotal

I am  new to R and would like some help on the survey function

I am using svyby function to do cross tab

for example: `svyby( ~bmi,~Race, design, svymean, na.rm = TRUE)`
and getting the result

```
                                  bmi_Obese          bmi_Overweight 
Asian                                29.84146         17.155935            
Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander     69.12672          9.839069                
NH White                             45.81656         22.619381                 
NH Black                             83.08938         23.581278               
Hispanic                             35.48914         29.117425                       
Native American/Alaskan Native       48.99318         20.636438                           
Other                                 0.00000          18.47743
```

Is there a way to get the total mean column and row in svyby, below is the output i am expecting as Stata would provide the total

```
Asian                                29.84146         17.155935            
Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander     69.12672          9.839069                
NH White                             45.81656         22.619381                 
NH Black                             83.08938         23.581278               
Hispanic                             35.48914         29.117425                       
Native American/Alaskan Native       48.99318         20.636438                           
Other                                 0.00000          18.47743  
**Total                                 ------           --------**
```

I have tried other functions inside svyby